# How to load a tflite model in script?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have converted the `.pb` file to `tflite` file using the **bazel**. Now I want to load this `tflite` model in my python script just to test that weather this is giving me correct output or not ?

Answer (score 64):

You can use **TensorFlow Lite Python interpreter** to load the tflite model in a python shell, and test it with your input data.

The code will be like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

***The above code is from TensorFlow Lite official guide***, *for more detailed information, read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python).*

Comment: which tensorflow version was used ? The Interpreter is not present now.

Comment: As I just tested with tensorflow 1.14.0, tflite Interpreter has been moved from **tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter** to **tf.lite.Interpreter**, see my updated answer above.

Comment: This is really great. I modified the file to actually test images, and I'm finding that my .tflite file must be invalid. If you're familiar with object detection, could you possibly check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736600/ssd-mobilenet-v1-with-tflite-giving-bad-output please?

Comment: How to  test instead of random data on test data

Comment: How can we make a prediction on all the dataset ? Like a ".predict(x_test)" ?

Answer (score 5):

### Using TensorFlow lite models in Python:

The verbosity of TensorFlow Lite is powerful because it allows you more control, but in many cases you just want to pass input and get an output, so I made a class that wraps this logic:

The following works with classification models from tfhub.dev, for example: https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224/1/metadata/1

```py
# Usage
model = TensorflowLiteClassificationModel("path/to/model.tflite")
(label, probability) = model.run_from_filepath("path/to/image.jpeg")
```

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


class TensorflowLiteClassificationModel:
    def __init__(self, model_path, labels, image_size=224):
        self.interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
        self.interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        self._input_details = self.interpreter.get_input_details()
        self._output_details = self.interpreter.get_output_details()
        self.labels = labels
        self.image_size=image_size

    def run_from_filepath(self, image_path):
        input_data_type = self._input_details[0]["dtype"]
        image = np.array(Image.open(image_path).resize((self.image_size, self.image_size)), dtype=input_data_type)
        if input_data_type == np.float32:
            image = image / 255.

        if image.shape == (1, 224, 224):
            image = np.stack(image*3, axis=0)

        return self.run(image)

    def run(self, image):
        """
        args:
          image: a (1, image_size, image_size, 3) np.array

        Returns list of [Label, Probability], of type List<str, float>
        """

        self.interpreter.set_tensor(self._input_details[0]["index"], image)
        self.interpreter.invoke()
        tflite_interpreter_output = self.interpreter.get_tensor(self._output_details[0]["index"])
        probabilities = np.array(tflite_interpreter_output[0])

        # create list of ["label", probability], ordered descending probability
        label_to_probabilities = []
        for i, probability in enumerate(probabilities):
            label_to_probabilities.append([self.labels[i], float(probability)])
        return sorted(label_to_probabilities, key=lambda element: element[1])
```

### Caution

However, you'll need to modify this to support different use cases, since I am passing images as input, and getting **classification** ([label, probability]) output. If you need text input (NLP), or other output (object detection outputs bounding boxes, labels and probabilities), classification (just labels), etc).

Also, if you are expecting different size image inputs, then you'd have to change the input size and reallocate the model (`self.interpreter.allocate_tensors()`). This is slow (inefficient). It's better to use the platform resizing functionality (e.g. Android graphics library) instead of using a TensorFlow lite model to do the resizing. Alternatively, you could resize the model with a separate model which would be much quicker to `allocate_tensors()` for.