# Can not load Tensorflow Lite model with tf.saved_model.load()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on Tensorlfow 2.0 to train a model. I want to reduce trained model size by converting to Tensorflow Lite model. But when I load TF Lite model, it will throw the error below at code line tf.saved_model.load():

```
TypeError: '_UserObject' object is not callable
```

I have done some searching and see that I need to use **tf.keras.models.load_model()** instead of **tf.saved_model.load()** to run the TF Lite model. But the searching answer is not clearly and I can not refer to my situation.

**Question:** Is there any way to run TF Lite model with tf.saved_model.load()? Or I need to convert all TF code to TF Keras code?

Comment: tf.saved_model.load() is not intended for loading tflite models. tflite models are for devices with limited computing power, and you should load them with a different API.

Comment: You can use [tfliteinterpreter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter) to load tflite models.

Comment: @Kaveh Thank you for fast reply. I'm planning to run TF Lite model on Jetson Nano kit. Is it possible to apply "tfliteinterpreter" for Jetson Nano kit?

Comment: @Hoang97 You can run the TFLite interpreter on various platforms. If it's [Linux](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#linux_platform), use [C++](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_c) or [Python API](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python)

Comment: Hi! You can load tflite models like this .                                                                                                                                              
                                       interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")                        reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443411/how-to-load-a-tflite-model-in-script